# Trying to insert the contents of a csv file into different lists

Tags: python, database, csv, neural-network

I am trying to insert the contents of a csv file into multiple lists. For this I stripped the strings of the csv. Unfortunately I always get the Error "list index out of range" if I try to insert the contents of a line with the index of 1 or above. For the index 0 it somehow works.
I checked the output of the print(akt) function. On that basis it should work. 
I am using the iris dataset.
Edit: Maybe it's because of the last line of the dataset isn't it? There is an empty list at the end, I didn't see it at first.

```
import csv

x1 = []
x2 = []
colors = []

with open("iris.csv" ,"r") as csvfile:
    for line in csvfile:
        akt = line.strip().split(',')
        x1.append(akt[0])
        x2.append(akt[1])
        colors.append(akt[4])
        #print(akt)
    csvfile.close()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-247b0992263a> in <module>
      9         akt = line.strip().split(',')
     10         x1.append(akt[0])
---> 11         x2.append(akt[1])
     12         colors.append(akt[4].split('-'))
     13         #print(akt)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
['5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.9', '3.0', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.7', '3.2', '1.3', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.6', '3.1', '1.5', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.0', '3.6', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.4', '3.9', '1.7', '0.4', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.6', '3.4', '1.4', '0.3', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.0', '3.4', '1.5', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.4', '2.9', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.9', '3.1', '1.5', '0.1', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.4', '3.7', '1.5', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.8', '3.4', '1.6', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.8', '3.0', '1.4', '0.1', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.3', '3.0', '1.1', '0.1', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.8', '4.0', '1.2', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.7', '4.4', '1.5', '0.4', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.4', '3.9', '1.3', '0.4', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.1', '3.5', '1.4', '0.3', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.7', '3.8', '1.7', '0.3', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.1', '3.8', '1.5', '0.3', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.4', '3.4', '1.7', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.1', '3.7', '1.5', '0.4', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.6', '3.6', '1.0', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.1', '3.3', '1.7', '0.5', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.8', '3.4', '1.9', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.0', '3.0', '1.6', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.0', '3.4', '1.6', '0.4', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.2', '3.5', '1.5', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.2', '3.4', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.7', '3.2', '1.6', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.8', '3.1', '1.6', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.4', '3.4', '1.5', '0.4', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.2', '4.1', '1.5', '0.1', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.5', '4.2', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.9', '3.1', '1.5', '0.1', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.0', '3.2', '1.2', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.5', '3.5', '1.3', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.9', '3.1', '1.5', '0.1', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.4', '3.0', '1.3', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.1', '3.4', '1.5', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.0', '3.5', '1.3', '0.3', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.5', '2.3', '1.3', '0.3', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.4', '3.2', '1.3', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.0', '3.5', '1.6', '0.6', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.1', '3.8', '1.9', '0.4', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.8', '3.0', '1.4', '0.3', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.1', '3.8', '1.6', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['4.6', '3.2', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.3', '3.7', '1.5', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['5.0', '3.3', '1.4', '0.2', 'Iris-setosa']
['7.0', '3.2', '4.7', '1.4', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.4', '3.2', '4.5', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.9', '3.1', '4.9', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.5', '2.3', '4.0', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.5', '2.8', '4.6', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.7', '2.8', '4.5', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.3', '3.3', '4.7', '1.6', 'Iris-versicolor']
['4.9', '2.4', '3.3', '1.0', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.6', '2.9', '4.6', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.2', '2.7', '3.9', '1.4', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.0', '2.0', '3.5', '1.0', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.9', '3.0', '4.2', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.0', '2.2', '4.0', '1.0', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.1', '2.9', '4.7', '1.4', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.6', '2.9', '3.6', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.7', '3.1', '4.4', '1.4', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.6', '3.0', '4.5', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.8', '2.7', '4.1', '1.0', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.2', '2.2', '4.5', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.6', '2.5', '3.9', '1.1', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.9', '3.2', '4.8', '1.8', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.1', '2.8', '4.0', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.3', '2.5', '4.9', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.1', '2.8', '4.7', '1.2', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.4', '2.9', '4.3', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.6', '3.0', '4.4', '1.4', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.8', '2.8', '4.8', '1.4', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.7', '3.0', '5.0', '1.7', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.0', '2.9', '4.5', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.7', '2.6', '3.5', '1.0', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.5', '2.4', '3.8', '1.1', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.5', '2.4', '3.7', '1.0', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.8', '2.7', '3.9', '1.2', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.0', '2.7', '5.1', '1.6', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.4', '3.0', '4.5', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.0', '3.4', '4.5', '1.6', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.7', '3.1', '4.7', '1.5', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.3', '2.3', '4.4', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.6', '3.0', '4.1', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.5', '2.5', '4.0', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.5', '2.6', '4.4', '1.2', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.1', '3.0', '4.6', '1.4', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.8', '2.6', '4.0', '1.2', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.0', '2.3', '3.3', '1.0', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.6', '2.7', '4.2', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.7', '3.0', '4.2', '1.2', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.7', '2.9', '4.2', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.2', '2.9', '4.3', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.1', '2.5', '3.0', '1.1', 'Iris-versicolor']
['5.7', '2.8', '4.1', '1.3', 'Iris-versicolor']
['6.3', '3.3', '6.0', '2.5', 'Iris-virginica']
['5.8', '2.7', '5.1', '1.9', 'Iris-virginica']
['7.1', '3.0', '5.9', '2.1', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.3', '2.9', '5.6', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.5', '3.0', '5.8', '2.2', 'Iris-virginica']
['7.6', '3.0', '6.6', '2.1', 'Iris-virginica']
['4.9', '2.5', '4.5', '1.7', 'Iris-virginica']
['7.3', '2.9', '6.3', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.7', '2.5', '5.8', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica']
['7.2', '3.6', '6.1', '2.5', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.5', '3.2', '5.1', '2.0', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.4', '2.7', '5.3', '1.9', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.8', '3.0', '5.5', '2.1', 'Iris-virginica']
['5.7', '2.5', '5.0', '2.0', 'Iris-virginica']
['5.8', '2.8', '5.1', '2.4', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.4', '3.2', '5.3', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.5', '3.0', '5.5', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica']
['7.7', '3.8', '6.7', '2.2', 'Iris-virginica']
['7.7', '2.6', '6.9', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.0', '2.2', '5.0', '1.5', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.9', '3.2', '5.7', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica']
['5.6', '2.8', '4.9', '2.0', 'Iris-virginica']
['7.7', '2.8', '6.7', '2.0', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.3', '2.7', '4.9', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.7', '3.3', '5.7', '2.1', 'Iris-virginica']
['7.2', '3.2', '6.0', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.2', '2.8', '4.8', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.1', '3.0', '4.9', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.4', '2.8', '5.6', '2.1', 'Iris-virginica']
['7.2', '3.0', '5.8', '1.6', 'Iris-virginica']
['7.4', '2.8', '6.1', '1.9', 'Iris-virginica']
['7.9', '3.8', '6.4', '2.0', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.4', '2.8', '5.6', '2.2', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.3', '2.8', '5.1', '1.5', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.1', '2.6', '5.6', '1.4', 'Iris-virginica']
['7.7', '3.0', '6.1', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.3', '3.4', '5.6', '2.4', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.4', '3.1', '5.5', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.0', '3.0', '4.8', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.9', '3.1', '5.4', '2.1', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.7', '3.1', '5.6', '2.4', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.9', '3.1', '5.1', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica']
['5.8', '2.7', '5.1', '1.9', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.8', '3.2', '5.9', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.7', '3.3', '5.7', '2.5', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.7', '3.0', '5.2', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.3', '2.5', '5.0', '1.9', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.5', '3.0', '5.2', '2.0', 'Iris-virginica']
['6.2', '3.4', '5.4', '2.3', 'Iris-virginica']
['5.9', '3.0', '5.1', '1.8', 'Iris-virginica']
['']
```

Comment: You say you tried `print(akt)`  - could you do that again and post the result? Do the print right after the split not at the end. We want to see the value right when the error occurs. I notice you aren't using the csv module. I don't think it would explain your problem, but using it instead of split can solve other problems like commas embedded in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a row only has one column in it. You didn't catch it with `print(akt)` because you only print the current row *after* the exception, so the failing row is never seen.

You need to check inputs and develop an error handling policy. Here is an example where I've updated to use the csv module and sanity check the row before trying to use it. I don't know your situation so I added cases to ignore one type of error but raise an exception on another.

```
import csv

x1 = []
x2 = []
colors = []

with open("iris.csv" ,"r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile):
        for i, akt in enumerate(csvfile, 1):
            # debug
            # print(akt)
            # Your error policy here. As an example, I'm going to allow
            # empty lines but not miscounted columns
            if not akt:
                continue
            if len(akt) != 5:
                raise ValueError("Invalid column in iris.csv line {}".format(i))
            x1.append(akt[0])
            x2.append(akt[1])
            colors.append(akt[4])
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much. I was pretty sure that every list had some content inside of it, but there is an empty list at the end.

Comment: @znked - an empty line at the end of a csv is very common. Not surprised you bumped into it.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use `pandas` whenever I deal with csv files

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")
columns = df.columns

x1 = df[columns[0]].tolist()
x2 = df[columns[1]].tolist()
colors  = df[columns[4]].tolist()
```